# Dominion: Can travellers (Peasant, Page) be Upgraded or Trade Routed?

Tags: dominion, dominion-adventures

The upgrades of Peasant and Page (Soldier, Fugitive, Disciple etc) are not in the supply. But can they still be trashed by Trade Route, or can they be upgraded by Upgrade? For example, a Disciple has a technical value of 5 - can it be upgraded to Gold by Upgrade?

Answer (score 5):

Yes. The cards in the traveler lines have costs so that they can be considered for cards such as Upgrade - in all such cases, you just ignore the "*" in their cost (just as you do for Peddler). So it is perfectly legitimate to trash a Disciple with Upgrade in order to gain a Gold.

The main thing that you can't do with those cards is interact with their piles outside of the exchange mechanism - you can't return them with Ambassador, and you can't gain them with something like Workshop.

Comment: And trashing them for example with Trade Route (or any other trasher) is also OK? And then they are trashed outside the game, just like those cards that are in the supply?

Comment: Absolutely, although trashed doesn't necessarily mean gone - there are a few cards that let you gain stuff from the trash, and you can legitimately target non-supply cards that have been trashed (so, for example, Graverobber can gain a Disciple from the trash).

Comment: And one more clarification about travellers: if I disciple a traveller, do I gain a copy of that one just like with any other card? For example, if I disciple a Fugitive, do I gain a copy of the Fugitive?

Comment: @Sakari No; Disciple works the same as Workshop, which the answer explains cannot be used to gain those cards. Basically, "gain" always means "from the supply" unless it specifically says somewhere else.